# JMeter run testplan for 2 hours with a maximum number of execution per hour

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan which performs creates an item (the process is more than 500 requests organizied in transaction controllers) in the application. I want to start the testplan to create 160 items with a maximum of 80 items per hour using 5 threads( each thread will select a random creator for the item using random csv Dataset)

I am using arrival thread group like this
[image]

the 1,3 arrival per minutes comes from 160 items / 120 minutes.

Jmeter will hang when I execute as above.

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Arrivals Thread Group is a good choice, your arrival rate is too low so the Thread Group doesn't start any threads and fails to stop them when the "Hold Target Rate" period ends. If the Arrivals Thread Group is your strict requirement I think you need to request the fix via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

In the meantime I would suggest considering switching to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) combination, the suggested configuration and the evidence of its work are in the below image:

[image]

Comment: The Throughput shaping timer could be applied on a single request. In my case create item is a complex of over 500 requests organized in transaction controllers (login, check configs as so far and so on).

Comment: Throughput Shaping Timer could be applied to the Samplers which are in the Timer's [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide). Also according to JMeter threads model you cannot have samplers with different throughputs in a single [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) because JMeter waits for previous sampler to finish before starting the next one so all samplers will be executed at the speed of slowest component

Comment: ok you suggest to use 0.222222 for Start RPS and End RPS. How did you calculate this ?

Comment: Any updates on how you have calculated the value 0.22222?